# What does it mean to say that decorators are more transparent than adapters?

Tags: design-patterns

I have read that *decorators* are more transparent to the client than *adapters* and it is this *transparency* that makes nested decoration possible. What is actually meant by *transparency* in this context?

P.S: I know both these design patterns. So you can base your answer on that premise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A decorator takes an object of a given type A, and wraps it into an object of the same type A. The client can use the decorated object as if it used the actual object, since they have the same type.

An adapter takes an object of a given type A, and wraps it into an object of another type B. A client which used the original type A must then be adapted to use the other type B.

That said, if we use the adapter pattern, it's precisely because a client needs an object of a type B, and we only have an object of type A. So we wrap it into an adapter to make it an object of type B.

The two patterns use the same principle (wrapping), but for diferent purposes. A decorator to change the behavior of the original object. An adapter to change its type.

Comment: what about transparency part?

Comment: That's what I explain in the first part: the client uses the decorator the same way it uses the decorated object, because they have the same type. It's transparent to the client. You can write bytes to a BufferedOutputStream the same way as you write them to a FileOutputStream, because they're both OutputStreams.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference for client between using decorator and decorated object (both have same interface). Thus decorator is transparent (i.e. invisible to client). Decorator also can be decorated by other decorators - that will not affect client. Client still can *think* that he is working with decorated object.

Nice sample is `Streams`. You can pass stream which decorated with any amount of decorators (zipping, encryption, buffering) but those decorators will stay invisible for any client which works with stream.

Actually I don't understand why adapter can be considered transparent. Client should not know type of adaptee, and client cannot treat adapter as adaptee, because they have different interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the how are Decorators transparent is more straightforward than why are Adapters sneaky or turgid. Decorators tend to get nested more often to mass functionality (that's often orthogonal, e.g. the BufferedFileWriter adds buffering, which doesn't really alter the basic operations of the class its wrapping: it's delegating those back to the original). Typically, you can see pretty easily what a Decorator is doing because it's cloaking itself in the original interface.

Adapters can be equally transparent. I would guess the reason that nesting Adapters is more difficult is you are talking about transforming some state object. Then you quickly get into all the ugliness that implies (one of the things that happens in MVC as it grows). So for instance, I have an old app that will give me a risk rating given a bunch of inputs. There's a new web interface that wants to use it, but it needs the data in another format. We can't change the original code so we introduce an Adapter that translates. What's it translating? Generally some state representation. So if the interface is different, it's going to take the inputs and convert and rejigger them, if the outputs need further massaging, ditto. If you layer multiple adapters, you will quickly find yourself having a harder time figuring out who contributed what to the final object that was presented (to either the service or back to the consumer).

Decorators are generally not used for such translation jobs, but rather for supplementing the functionality of something to which we either don't have the code, or, again, where the new functionality is orthogonal, and thus, we are allowing the user to user or not use one or more decorators.